# Good approach to clean application data programmatically in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory, android-activity, picasso

When I use RecyclerView and/or Picasso.
It seems to cache and store alot of data in my application.
However, I want to delete the stored data and the cache in a simple way whenever I am exiting my app.

1. What is the simplest way to delete all data stored in your created app programmatically?
2. What is the latest or the efficient way to tell Picasso to not store or cache images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picasso has `evictAll()` API to clear cache. Also you can set Picasso disk cache size to something small or zero.